# Handlebars template doesn't work main css and detect click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am using handlebars and phonegap. I have this code:

```
$( '#text' ).click(function() {
    var path = 'template/template.html'
    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        cache: true,
        success: function (data) {
            var source = data;
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            var data = {};
            $("#div").html(template(data));
        }
    });
});
```

template

```
<input type="button" data-inline="true" value="Value" id="button">
```

When I load the template, it doesn't take the css of the main page and I can't detect neither the click on the id button.

Thanks

Comment: I dont think your `url` can be and html page and is any data being returned?

Comment: I get the template but I dont know why when I call the id button via jquery doesn't work

Comment: what do you mean by "call the id button"? and how are you calling it?

Comment: Your data object is empty

Comment: 1. It's not great practice to have two things named the same within the same scope (var = data in your case).
2. Make sure the data passed into the success is the string you expect. I have a working fiddle here that may be of some help http://jsfiddle.net/whit1440/8HXv3/1/